# Ag-Grid row data .map param.value

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using Ag-Grid React - and trying to map the params.value in the rowData using:

```
{ 
  headerName: "Assigned To", 
  field: "assignedTo",
  colId: "assignedTo001",
  sortable: true, 
  floatingFilter: true, 
  filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
  cellRendererFramework: function(params) {
    if(!params.data.assignedTo) {
      return ''
    }
    // return JSON.stringify(params.data.assignedTo)
    params.data.assignedTo.map((user) => {
      if(user) {
        return JSON.stringify(user)
      }else{
        return 'Not assigned'
      }
    })
  }
},
```

The commented out line above the .map `// return JSON.stringify(params.data.assignedTo)` works fine, but I need to map through the array to display the user.uid or user.name.

I started off trying to use the default params.value, that did't work so I switched to using the params.data.

The code above is not working, getting a `Uncaught Error: cellRendererFramework(...): Nothing was returned from render.` error.

What is the best way to return multiple values from an array in a row?

Comment: You aren't returning the result of `params.data.assignedTo.map((user) => { ... }`, which probably needs to be converted from an array to string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `return`  statement before `params.data.assignedTo.map((user) => {`

Comment: oh damn, lol - Thanks! got lost in all of these return(s)